# how can i while loop my game? (text based rpg)

Tags: python

this is one of the minigames part of a larger game I have, I want to make it so that if the player loses this game they return to an exit screen. if the player wins they go to the main storyline. I think while looping would be good way to do this but I'm not sure how. Whenever you win or lose this game you go to the main storyline no matter what.

```
import time, os
import ascii as a

def clear_console():
  os.system('clear')

import typewriter as typewriter

def press_enter():
  print("\n\npress enter to continue.")
  input()
     
black = "\033[0;30m"
red = "\033[0;31m"
green = "\033[0;32m"
yellow = "\033[0;33m"
blue = "\033[0;34m"
magenta = "\033[0;35m"
cyan = "\033[0;36m"
white = "\033[0;37m"
bright_black = "\033[0;90m"
bright_red = "\033[0;91m"
bright_green = "\033[0;92m"
bright_yellow = "\033[0;93m"
bright_blue = "\033[0;94m"
bright_magenta = "\033[0;95m"
bright_cyan = "\033[0;96m"
bright_white = "\033[0;97m"

# Initial Steps to invite in the game:
remember = ("figure out what the secret code is before the evil pixie finds you and sucks your soul...")
print("")
typewriter.write(a.evil_pixie_art, 0.0001)
press_enter()
clear_console()

# The parameters we require to execute the game:
def main():
    global count
    global display
    global word
    global already_guessed
    global length
    global play_game
    words_to_guess = "treasure"
    word = (words_to_guess)
    length = len(word)
    count = 0
    display = '_' * length
    already_guessed = []
    play_game = ""

# Initializing all the conditions required for the game:
def hangman():
    global count
    global display
    global word
    global already_guessed
    global play_game
    limit = 7
    guess = input("the secret code: " + display + " enter a letter: \n")
    guess = guess.strip()
    if len(guess.strip()) == 0 or len(guess.strip()) >= 2 or guess <= "9":
        print("This is not the correct input! Please enter letters only...\n")
        hangman()

    elif guess in word:
        already_guessed.extend([guess])
        index = word.find(guess)
        word = word[:index] + "_" + word[index + 1:]
        display = display[:index] + guess + display[index + 1:]
        print(display + "\n")

    elif guess in already_guessed:
        print("try again...\n")

    else:
        count += 1
        if count == 7:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("   _____ \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |       \n"
                "  |       \n"
                "  |       \n"
                "__|__     \n")
          typewriter.write("you lost all your chances, the evil pixie has caught up to you...\n", 0.04)
          print(" ")
          typewriter.write("before you could even think the pixie blows a dark, black powder all over you causing you to start choking. You slowly feel you lose your concious...", 0.04)
          print("")
         
        elif count == 6:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("   _____ \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     |\n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     O \n"
                "  |      \n"
                "  |      \n" 
                "__|__\n")
          print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " guesses remaining\n")

        elif count == 5:
          time.sleep(1) 
          print("   _____ \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     |\n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     O \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |       \n"
                "__|__\n")
          print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " guesses remaining\n")

        elif count == 4:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("   _____ \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     O \n"
                "  |    /| \n"
                "  |       \n"
                "__|__\    n")
          print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " guesses remaining\n")

        elif count == 3:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("   _____ \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     |\n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     O \n"
                "  |    /|\ \n"
                "  |      \n" 
                "__|__\n")
          print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " guesses remaining\n")

        elif count == 2:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("   _____ \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     |\n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     O \n"
                "  |    /|\ \n"
                "  |      \ \n"
                "__|__\n")
          print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " last guess remaining\n")

        elif count == 1:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("   _____ \n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     |\n"
                "  |     | \n"
                "  |     O \n"
                "  |    /|\ \n"
                "  |    / \ \n"
                "__|__      \n")
          print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " guesses remaining\n")
         
            

    if word == '_' * length:
      typewriter.write("You found out the code and the large stone door opened to let you in, as you ran in you saw the evil pixie behind you and widened your eyes. Right before she could get in the door slammed shut causing you to breathe a sigh of relief. ", 0.04)
      print(" ")
      press_enter()
      clear_console()
        
    elif count != limit:
        hangman()

main()

hangman()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to address what you want to do, I utilize a very basic game setup pattern that works well for me as shown below:

```
# Function to request input and verify input type is valid
def getInput(prompt, respType= None):
    while True:
        resp = input(prompt)
        if respType == str or respType == None:
            break
        else:
            try:
                resp = respType(resp)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid input, please try again')
    return resp  

# function to initiate game play and control game termination
def playgame():
    if getInput('Do you want to play? (y/n)').lower() == 'y':
            while True:
                game_input = getInput('Enter an Integer', int)
                # . . .  Process the data here . . . #
                if getInput("Play Again? (y/n)").lower() == 'n':
                    break
    print('Good bye')
```

Of course you can change the text to suit your personal choices, but inside the basic while loop place the code for your specific game and return back when it is over.